# Maven ear problem

Tags: maven, ear

I'm finishing my project build (with maven), and it's working great. Now I just have to "pack it", as an ear.

All I need to do is pack 3 dependencies, one .jar and 2 .war. Don't ask me how, that was the way it was done before (with ant), and I'm translating it to maven - next I'll organize the packages, so we can be more productive.

However, I'm having a few problems. First, the package is named null-${version}.ear. It copies itself right to the repository, but in the target folder is wrongly named. And second, it's copying all the other packages dependencies. I want to know what can I do about the null name, and the copying of the packages.

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>owner</groupId>
        <artifactId>coreisp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>owner</groupId>
    <artifactId>coreisp-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <name>Projeto CoreISP</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>coreisp-core</artifactId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>coreisp-initializer</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>coreisp-site</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${application.id}-${pom.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>owner</groupId>
                            <artifactId>coreisp-core</artifactId>
                            <includeInApplicationXml>
                            true
                            </includeInApplicationXml>
                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                        </jarModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>owner</groupId>
                            <artifactId>
                            coreisp-initializer
                            </artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                        </webModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>owner</groupId>
                            <artifactId>
                            coreisp-site
                            </artifactId>
                            <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The null is coming from your definition by <finalName>...</finalName> (Why do you try this and don't use the convention?). Furthermore you are using  ${pom.groupId} which is outdated you should use ${project.groupId} etc. instead (Doesn't maven produce a warning about that?). Why are you not using a SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: I copied the pom from another project, which started from scratch as a maven project. This one I'm trying to translate. Thanks, I did all your suggestions! And the snapshot, it's the old code base version.

Comment: Do we must specify dependency in the ear pom? why can't I use the parent dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the  element from your POM, the application.id property is what gives you the "null" name.

As to ensure that transitive dependencies do not end up in your EAR I suggest you specify explicitly in your POM what you do want and what you do not want. In order to keep a dependency out all you need to do is define it in your POM with a scope of provided. I know it's a painful job, but in my opinion it's worth it, to ensure that you get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I thought that puting them as provided wouldn't package them in the final ear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just explaining what I mean: I put the dependencies as provided, but THEIR dependencies didn't get into the package, while they did. Thanks again.